# Extract integer from char buffer

Tags: c

I have a very simple problem in C. I am reading a file linewise, and store it in
a buffer

```
char line[80];
```

Each line has the following structure:

```
Timings results : 2215543
Timings results : 22155431
Timings results : 221554332
Timings results : 2215543
```

What I am trying to do, is to extract the integer value from this line. Does C here provide any simple function that allows me to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Can use sscanf per line, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int time = -1;
char* str = "Timings results : 120012";

int n = sscanf(str, "Timings results : %d", &time);
```

in this case n == 1 means success

Answer (score 2):

Yes - try [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

```
   int n=atoi(str);
```

In your example, you have a fixed prefix before the integer, so you could simply add an offset to szLine before passing it to atoi, e.g.

```
   int offset=strlen("Timings results : ");
   int timing=atoi(szLine + offset);
```

Pretty efficient, but doesn't cope well with lines which aren't as expected. You could check each line first though:

```
   const char * prefix="Timings results : ";
   int offset=strlen(prefix);
   char * start=strstr(szLine, prefix);
   if (start)
   {
       int timing=atoi(start+offset);

       //do whatever you need to do
   }
   else
   {
       //line didn't match
   }
```

You can also use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) for parsing lines like this, which makes for more concise code:

```
   int timing;
   sscanf(szLine, "Timings results : %d", &timing);
```

Finally, see also [Parsing Integer to String C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478528/parsing-integer-to-string-c) for further ideas.

Comment: You still have to parse the string because doesn't atoi() return 0 if your string starts with a non-numerical value?

Comment: `strtol` is better than `atoi` as it allows you to handle errors.