# Extract Number from Char* Array (C-String)

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have a string that occurs in this format:

`.word 40`

I would like to extract the integer part. The integer part is always different but the string always starts with `.word`. I have a tokenizer function which works on everything except for this. When I put `.word` (.word with a space) as a delimiter it returns null.

How can I extract the number?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this may be what you are seeking
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031872/extract-integer-from-char-buffer

Comment: You should research to see if there exists a parser or lexer for the language you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) to extract formated data from a string. (It works just like scanf, but reading the data from a string instead of from standard input)

Comment: A code example would be nice, since it is stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **[strtok()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtok.html)** to extract the two strings with space as an delimiter.

**[Online Demo:](http://www.ideone.com/476Oj)**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main ()
    {
        char str[] =".Word 40";
        char * pch;
        printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
        pch = strtok (str," ");
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            printf ("%s\n",pch);
            pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
Splitting string ".Word 40" into tokens:
.Word
40
```

If you want the number `40` as a numeric value rather than a string then you can further use 
**[atoi()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/atoi.html)** to convert it to a numeric value.

Comment: Epic win to include the online demo!

Answer (score 1):

Check the string with

```
strncmp(".word ", (your string), 6);
```

If this returns 0, then your string starts with ".word " and you can then look at (your string) + 6 to get to the start of the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[] = "A=17280, B=-5120. Summa(12150) > 0";
char *p = str;
do
{
if (isdigit(*p) || *p == "-" && isdigit(*(p+1)))
printf("%ld ", strtol(p,&p,0);
else
p++;
}while(*p!= '\0');
```

This code write in console all digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo;
scanf("%*s %d", &foo);
```

The asterisk tells scanf not to store the string it reads.  Use fscanf if you're reading from a file, or sscanf if the input is already in a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
char* string = ".word 40";
char number[5];
unsigned int length = strlen(string);
strcpy(number, string + length - 2);
```

Comment: That gets you the characters "40" but not an integer.

Comment: He didn't specify he wants an integer. He said "I would like to extract the integer part" but not in which format.