# To get integer from string

Tags: c, arrays, casting

I am in trouble about getting integer from string and using it. I have:

```
char *string = "I 17 24 flying bits";
```

I want to take 17 and 24 as integer and use them. Pointer casting is out of question, how can i get those integers and use them ?

Comment: try function atoi & strtok

Comment: Read about [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). The `strtol` function allows you to validate that a string is a number or not, something that `atoi` is not able to do.

Comment: @michaeltang: I wouldn't recommend atoi() to new programmers; using it correctly is exceedingly difficult in the presence of unvalidated input.  strtol() seems harder to use, but in fact is easier to use correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a, b;
int count = sscanf(array, "%*s %d %d", &a, &b);
if (count == 3) // then you matched three tokens, proceed, else failed to match
```

Comment: What if I don't know the number of integers in the string?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: Go for the `strtok()/strtol()` approach.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: you have no idea, or is there a maximum number of integers?  If say the max is 5 or 6 or whatever, just add more tokens in the scanf.  If the number is potentially very many, then yes, use strtok_r() (not strtok() which is thread-unsafe) and strtol().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) standard library function. Include `<string.h>` header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtok along with atoi() and isdigit().
you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892681/extract-number-from-char-array-c-string) to get idea. same logic as one of the answer there can be used.

Comment: `atoi()` is safely usable only if the numbers to be read do not include `0`, as `0` is used to detect a conversion error.

Comment: @alk ya then using isdigit()||atoi() can help.