# How to extract a number from a string in C

Tags: c

I am working on a project for school but I can't figure out how I can extract the year from a date in a string `"20-02-2015"` the date is always of the form `XX-XX-XXXX`

Is there some way to use some kind of scan function?

Comment: I think my upvote will enable u to upvote @Rikayan answer:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
char date[]="20-02-2015";
int d,m,y;
sscanf(date,"%d-%d-%d",&d,&m,&y);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked yes, if i had more then 15 reputation i would have upvoted you :)

Comment: @Dennis You will, later. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your string is given as `char* str` or as `char str[]`, you can try this:

```
int day,mon,year;
sscanf(str,"%d-%d-%d",&day,&mon,&year);
```

Or you can try this, for a slightly better performance (by avoiding the call to `sscanf`):

```
int year = 1000*(str[6]-'0')+100*(str[7]-'0')+10*(str[8]-'0')+(str[9]-'0');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strtok()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function to split a string (and specify the delimiter to use)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{  

 char *date = malloc(10);
 char *day = NULL;
 char *month = NULL;
 char *year = NULL;

 strcpy(date, "01-03-2014");

 day = strtok(date, "-");
 printf("%s\n",day);

 month = strtok(NULL, "-");
 printf("%s\n",month);

 year = strtok(NULL, "-");
 printf("%s\n",year);


free(date);
    return 0;
}
```

the output :

```
 01
 03
 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the `%d-%d-%d` format.

If reading from STDIN, use `scanf`, from a file use `fscanf` and from a string use `sscanf`

Comment: But which scan function should i use then? Because i only know the scanf() to read keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the string using strtok(date,"-") then can use atoi() to get the date, month and year as numbers. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116327/to-get-integer-from-string/22116364?noredirect=1#comment33551696_22116364) it can help you

Comment: No need to use `strtok` if number of tokens is known and small.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay i told the possibilities in general. ya in this case since format is fixed can use sscanf() easily.

Answer (score 0):

As other have suggested `"%d-%d-%d"`.

To add error checking, should code need to insure no trailing garbage and all was there:

```
char date[80];
fgets(data, sizeof date, stdin);

int d,m,y;
in n;
int cnt = sscanf(date, "%d-%d-%d%n", &d, &m, &y, &n);

if (cnt == 3 && date[n] == '\n') Good();
else Bad();
```